# Transition effect not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm creating a navbar and i'm changing the font size of a brand when scroll top is greater than 10 as you can see below . i just wanna make brand font size small or bigger smoothly. just like transitions in css3 . is there any efficient way of doing that???

```
 var a = $(".navbar-default").offset().top;
 $(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('.navbar-default').addClass("scrolled");
    $('.navbar-brand').css({"font-size":"20px"});
  } else {
    $('.navbar-default').removeClass("scrolled");
    $('.navbar-brand').css({"font-size":"26px"});
  }
});
```

HTML

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand-font-size navbar-brand scroll" href="#home">Shopify</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center" style="position:relative;left:300px;">
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#about">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#portfolio">Accessories</a></li>
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#clients">Men</a></li>
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#team">Women</a></li> 
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#blog">FAQ's</a></li>
          <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">Order Now</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right icons">
          <li class="icon-border"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search icons-size"></i></a></li>
          <li class="icon-border"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart icons-size"></i></a></li>
          <li class="icon-border"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-align-justify icons-size"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried using jquery's `.animate()` on the font-size?

Comment: Increment/decrements font by 1 relative to 30fps, meaning using timeouts. 
30fps is 33.33 ms per increment. so 33ms should do it. This would be the caveman style hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to animate *like* CSS, you can use CSS:

```
.navbar-brand{
    -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
    transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do two things, in order of importance:

- first use a debounce function to call your update function a lot less often, see Ben Alman's one here http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html
- further optimization is to just update css if you are changing the state, store the previous value of `$(this).scrollTop() > 10` comparison. If it doesn't change just do nothing.

These and using css transitions to make the animation smoother as suggested in another answer will make the end result more beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use CSS to make the font-size smaller. Try this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('nav').addClass('small');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('small');
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
}
button {
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: font-size 1s;
}
nav.small button {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <button>Home</button>
  <button>About</button>
  <button>Products</button>
  <button>Contact</button>
</nav>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```